# how to list all doc in a mongodb collection with sharedb-cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sharedb

it is my client-demo. I want to get all doc in the "file" collection. but i get null

[image]

I use the mongo shell to test it. I find the doc data exists
[image]

I'm sure the client connects to server successfully. cause when i invoke connection.get('file','test'), console log is the same as mongo shell. log text (Delta { ops: [ { insert: 'Hi!12323232' } ] })
[image]

i expected that query.results is an array contains correct docs.

Comment: Would it be easier to simply copy and paste your script, rather than taking a screenshot, uploading it, and then sharing the link to the image in this question?

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer in the [sharedb document](https://share.github.io/sharedb/queries)
I should add the ready event callback:

```js
var query = connection.createFetchQuery('file', {}, null);

query.on('ready', () => {
    query.results.forEach((doc) => console.log(doc.data));
});
```